# Prevent function from being called immediately when passing arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, trumbowyg

I have the following code, which works

```
var settings = trumbowyg.o.plugins.giphycrumbs;
settings = $.extend(true, {},
    defaultOptions,
    trumbowyg.o.plugins.giphycrumbs || {}
);

if(!settings.open_modal) {
    settings.open_modal = function() {
        $(settings.modal_selector).modal('show');
    }
}

trumbowyg.addBtnDef('giphycrumbs', {
    fn: settings.open_modal
});
```

Where `settings.open_modal` is executed when a button is pressed.

However, I want to define this function elsewhere (In the plugins section of trumbowyg instead of inside the plugin itself), but to do that, I need to be able to pass a selector to it. I've already done this with a similar `close_modal` function, but I'm having issues with the `open_modal` function.

Here is how I would define the function the way I want to:

```
plugins: {
    giphycrumbs: {
        ...
        modal_selector: '#giphy_modal',
        close_modal: function(selector) {
            $(selector).modal('hide');
        },
        open_modal: function(selector) {
            $(selector).modal('show');
        }
    },
}
```

This would mean that my `addBtnDef` call would be changed to something like:

```
trumbowyg.addBtnDef('giphycrumbs', {
    fn: settings.open_modal(settings.modal_selector)
});
```

However, this causes the function to be ran *immediately upon initialization* instead of waiting for the button to be pressed as it did before I added the selector to the function.

How can I make this code wait for the button to be pressed before running the function, like it did before I added the selector?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to fix this, though I'd prefer a better solution which doesn't require an extra function to work.

First, declare `settings` *outside* of the plugin init, and assign the settings to it the same way as before.

```
var settings = null;

...

giphycrumbs: {
    init: function (trumbowyg) {
        settings = trumbowyg.o.plugins.giphycrumbs;
        ...
```

Next, create a new function which does not use any arguments which just calls `settings.open_modal(settings.modal_selector)`.

```
function run_open_modal() {
    settings.open_modal(settings.modal_selector);
}
```

And call that function in the addBtnDef call.

```
trumbowyg.addBtnDef('giphycrumbs', {
    fn: run_open_modal
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is open_modal declared beforehand? Because, if it isn't, you could declare the settings as:

```
 if(!settings.open_modal) {
 settings.open_modal = function(selector) {
    selector= selector||settings.modal_selector.
      $(selector).modal('show');
   }
}
```

So in case you can redefine it, make the orginal closure accept a selector. If you don't pass one, then it defaults to its initial behavior.

Comment: I was actually trying to remove the pre-defined function, because it will be different for every user probably.